# maven exclude tests with surefire excludeTests option

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a large project with sub-projects and want to use `excludesFile` to exclude test failures, and ignore them until the tests are fixed.

I believe there might be a way of achieving this with surefire plugin `excludesFile` option [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludesFile).

I am very new to maven and would like get some examples or pointers on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

To use excludesFile option,

1. Create a file containing file name patterns of your test files that you want to exclude.
   Example:Create a file at src/main/resources/exclude.txt with below 2 lines.
   **/*1.java 
   **/*2.java
2. Add following in your maven-surefile-plugin configuration.

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.20</version>
           <configuration>
               <excludesFile>src/test/resources/exclude.txt</excludesFile>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```
3. You are done. All test files ending with 1.java and 2.java will be excluded.

There is other way also to exclude any tests from execution by using  configuration in maven-surefire-plugin.

Example:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

More information can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I really would prefer doing it through a excludes file, which can be passed to subproject poms. Will consider this option if that does not work.

Comment: Ok. Modified the answer to use excludeFile option.

Comment: Can this be incorporated in the root level pom, with sub-projects inside, which are using the same excludes.txt outside of the src folder ?

Comment: Not very sure but worth a try. Also, checkout pluginManagement section in pom.

Comment: can exclude.txt be an empty file if nothing requires to be added ?